# Problems with IBM BladeCenter E type 8677

Tags: vmware-esxi, ibm, blade-server, bladecenter

We have an IBM BladeCenter E server with three blades, today I've tried to manage it through telnet, after logout it does not respond on  its default "Management Module" address (it was set to `10.0.150.10`, normally I've accessed it through web browser). I can connect to one of the blades through KVM where VMware ESXi is installed (and have IP set to `10.0.5.14`, still I can't connect to it through vSphere client). My question is, how can I connect to this beast to update firmware or other maintenance mode? We had problems with error messages like: 1. `Alert Text: Blade System Management Processor reset, persistent events will be regenerated.` 2. `Alert Text: Blade 2 is not responding on the management bus` 3. `Alert Text: Recovery Blade 2 is not responding on the management bus` 4. `Alert Text: Problem communicating with BSMP.`. I have tried to reseat blade number 2, alert message on web interface disappeared but alerts like these I have quoted still are incoming on my mail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the IBM Bladecenters in combination with VMWare there are a number of things to keep in mind.

Both VMWare and the Bladecenter use Vlans on the network cards. Make sure the BladeCenter switch has the right Vlan (or trunk) set to the switch, and to the port where the blade is connected. On the console of the VMWare server, make sure its management port is set to a proper vlan.

Now as for updating firmwares and such, on the management module there should be a reset switch, which you can press down by using a pensil or paperclip. It is completely safe to reset a management module on a running BladeCenter as that will not interfear with operation. Firmwares can obviously be updated from the MM's http interface.

If even after reset the web interface & telnet do not come up within resonable time, it might be wise to reset it to defaults. Consult the manual for your MM on how to do that.

Comment: Okay, I did a reset of MM and I can successfully login to blades with vSphere client, but now default MM address is `192.168.70.125` and our network firewall only accepts IPs from range `10.0.0.0/8`. How can I now change the IP of MM?

Comment: You should be able to connect with a crossover cable.

Comment: Either connect with a network crossover cable, or if its connected to a switch on the same network as your PC you can just add an IP to your network card in the windows network settings. Add an IP in the same range, something like 192.168.70.100 / 255.255.255.0 and you can connect directly to the MM. you can change the IP from the web interface.